# How to Fix TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading ' ')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

```
 const editOrder = (e, id) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setIsLoading(true);

    const orderConfig = {
      userID: order.userID,
      userEmail: order.userEmail,
      orderDate: order.orderDate,
      orderTime: order.orderTime,
      orderAmount: order.orderAmount,
      orderStatus: status,
      cartItems: order.cartItems,
      billingAddress: order.billingAddress,
      createdAt: order.createdAt,
      editedAt: Timestamp.now().toDate(),
    };

    try {
      setDoc(doc(db, "orders", id), orderConfig);

      setIsLoading(false);
      toast.success("Order status changes successfully");
      navigate("/adminorders");
    } catch (error) {
      setIsLoading(false);
      toast.error(error.message);
    }
  };
```

and this is save order page in firebase

```
 const saveOrder = () => {
    const today = new Date();
    const date = today.toDateString();
    const time = today.toLocaleTimeString();
    const orderConfig = {
      userID,
      userEmail,
      orderDate: date,
      orderTime: time,
      orderAmount: cartTotalAmount,
      orderStatus: "Not yet process...",
      cartItems,
      billingAddress,
      createdAt: Timestamp.now().toDate(),
    };

    try {
      addDoc(collection(db, "orders"), orderConfig);

      dispatch(CLEAR_CART())

      toast.success("Order saved")
      navigate('/checkout-success')
    } catch (error) {
      toast.error(error.message)

    }
  }
```

I tried to fix but the data in firebase it disappeared.
Cannot read property of null after 'order.'

More pictures in CheckOutFrom section of save order

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JL8tn.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1q7E.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unbG9.png)

and this is my error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woE4o.png)

Comment: you can add ? before .
order?.userID

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of error and also where is `order` coming from in first code snippet?

Comment: @Dharmaraj I edited the post and added more pictures. hope it can help me